# What to do if Cacti monitering server goes down in Centos 6.3?

Tags: centos, monitoring, cacti

I have successfully deployed cacti with plugins thold, nectar, realtime. Currently I am monitering my amazon ec2 servers and internal servers in my organization. but I afraid what to do In following situation

if any aws server disconnect due to problem of bandwidth but still running , how can I get its snmp data later on while it was disconnected ?

Is there any idea to store snmp data when no connection found and later send it to cacti ???

What should I do in such situations ?

What to do if my cacti itself goes down ?

Comment: If you understand your question correctly, this could help: [*"How do I collect SNMP readings from intermittently-connected sites?"*](http://serverfault.com/q/152022/97710)

Answer (score 1):

If your Cacti host looses connectivity to a destination, or if your Cacti server goes down, you'll end up with gaps in your RRD stores for those periods, and obviously the derived graphs. As SNMP is a point in time protocol, with no caching or history, and by default Cacti polls via SNMP and updates an RRD with the current data.

If you want to mitigate against an outage loosing usage data your only option would be to replace the snmp probes with your own custom probes (script), to pull log files from each server and import into a suitable rrd store on the cacti server. The log generation would require suitable client scripts be developed, deployed and scheduled on the target hosts to capture the desired information, along with a time stamp, to a log file.

The [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/index.php) web site contains numerous scripts that could be a basis for your resilient set of probes.